# Posting an image to Facebook with ShareKit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I've been successful so far in installing and getting ShareKit to post to Twitter, Email, and Photo Album. Easy enough.

However now I'm trying to get it to post to Facebook. I'm simply using the default button through the actionsheet for Facebook.

I have filled in App ID in the config of my ShareKit file. I have also added the CFBundleURLType stuff in the info.plist.

The issue is when I hit the "Post to Facebook" button, I get redirected to my native Facebook app, I see a dialog box that says "Loading..." for 1 second, then I'm redirected back to my app. Upon first try (without app permissions), it'll ask me to allow the app, so that parts just fine. However it's not posting or asking me to post the image.

What am I missing? Am I able to directly post images to FB? Or does it have to be a URL first or something? Also, am I suppose to enable SSO via the FB app settings? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies, I should have read the documentation more thoroughly.

Its step 7: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

Answer (score 3):

```
#import "SHK.h"
#import "SHKFacebook.h"

SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] title:imageTitle];
[SHKFacebook  shareItem:item];
```